# Highcharts column chart returning incorrect series index on click when using shared tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
             series: {
                 cursor: 'pointer',
                 point: {
                     events: {
                         click: function() {
                             alert("column index: " + this.series.columnIndex);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [216.4, 194.1]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [91.2, 83.5]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [52.4, 65.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [47.6, 39.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9mp9vhj/1/

Click on the top of the first column and you will see the message: "column index: 0" which is correct. Click on the middle or bottom of the first column and you will see other indeces.

if you set tooltip to be not shared everything starts working.

Is it Highcharts bug? How to get the correct column index with shared columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost seems like Highcharts isn't taking the x-value of the click into account, and only looks at the y-value of your click location (you can get every index if you click in the "correct" height).

It seems that the `event.target.point` is correct, while `event.point` (or `this`) is not. An example of how this workaround can be used to get the correct `columnIndex` as Highcharts is currently working ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/a9mp9vhj/2/)):

```
plotOptions: {
     series: {
         point: {
             events: {
                 click: function(event) {
                     alert("column index: " + event.target.point.series.columnIndex);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your fix worked fine. Anyway, it seems to be a Highcharts bug, I created an issue in their github: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4020

Comment: I cannot ask question due to my point limit , but if I change to bar in your code, Berlin show at the top and tokyo show at the bottom .How I can change tool tip to follow the same rule?